# Why update or insert is not working with 2 Composite key columns in WSO2 DAS RDBMS data publisher

Tags: mysql, wso2, bigdata, wso2-das

I try to create a RDBMS publisher for WSO2 DAS with 2 Composite key columns and "update or insert" as execution mode. However this publisher does not work.

When I modified it by selecting "insert" for execution mode it work well. One of selected composite key column is INT and other is STRING. This columns map to 2 columns in a MySQL table . This columns are INT(11) and TEXT.

Why this publisher not work with "update or insert" execution mode?

Comment: Are you using all the attributes of  stream for the composite key?
( In this case, does the stream contain only two attributes? )

Comment: In MySQL, a `TEXT` column cannot be used in an index.

Comment: After I delete and recreate relevant table, stream and publisher it is work fine.

Comment: @GihanDB Could you please share the changes you made when re-creating the table, stream and publisher?

Comment: I make new table with columns which have exactly same names to fields in Stream (Except current date time column which is automatically updating). However i'm not exactly sure that is the cause because we map columns.